Artinian modules and Socles
Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, and $M$ a module over $R$. I would like to see that the following conditions are equivalent:
1: $M$ is an artinian module
2: $\mathrm{Supp}(M)\subseteq \{\mathfrak{m}\}$ and the Socle of $M$ which is defined equivalently as $\mathrm{Hom}(R/\mathfrak{m},M)$ or as $(0\colon\mathfrak{m})_M$ is finite-dimensional.
If $M$ is itself finitely generated over $R$ then the equivalence is easy to see, so only the case where $M$ is not finitely generated is of interest.

Usually when people say "$(R,\mathfrak m)$" They mean $R$ is local with unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. Is that something you have left out?
